# Best way to gather data from a website for an Android application

Tags: android, web, data-retrieval

I'm trying to put together a new app for a project that will display train times for the user.

I know there are a couple of ways to go about this, but before I get started I wanted to get some help from you.

### My options

1. use a webview
2. Use a database linked to the website that has all of the data
3. Hard code all of the times
4. Ask the website for the data/access to the data.

This is the site:
http://www.njtransit.com/sf/sf_servlet.srv?hdnPageAction=LightRailTo

I was looking in the source to see if I could find anything, but came up blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method #4** is the best way. Request access to their  webservice that gives you results in xml/json. Your Android App then parses it and then display's it according to it's UI and give users some extra features that the website can't provide.

**Method 1)** Use a webview - (well, technically the easiest...but if you are simply opening the webpage, why should i use your application when a browser can do the same?)

**Method 2)** More or less the same as Method #4

**Method 3)** Train schedules might change, you'll have to update your app frequently.

Comment: Contacted the website. Got a developer registration link. They give me csv files with all the information. Now I just need to learn how to parse all of it. Thanks!

Comment: @user1316700, Use a CSV parser. Good luck, Cheers! :)